# How can root lock KDE sessions of all the other users

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, kde4

Every evening cron hibernates my PC for the night.

Now, since there is a chance that I won't be the person turning the computer on next morning, I would like to make sure that all the active sessions are properly secured behind screensavers prior to hibernation. Regular "su" nor similar methods of running programs with other users' permissions do not seem to work: apparently the programs or scripts do not have connections with the proper KDE sessions. I remember to manage it under KDE3 (although I can't recall the solution details), but since I migrated to KDE4 years ago the method did not work any more.

Would anybody put me in the right direction?

```
KDE 4.14.9
NAME=openSUSE
VERSION="13.2 (Harlequin)"
VERSION_ID="13.2"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE 13.2 (Harlequin) (x86_64)"
ID=opensuse
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:opensuse:13.2"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://opensuse.org/"
ID_LIKE="suse"
```

Thank you very much for your help.